# Fastest and slowest action potential

Tags: neuroscience, action-potential

When our instructor asked us about the speed of action potentials in cells, I told him that action potentials and two-wheelers travels at similar speeds. He thought that this is an 'interesting' way of looking at it.

Needless to say after the class I tried to figure out the minimum, average and maximum speed of action potentials in neurons. [Wiki helped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduction_velocity) but its not authoritative. Some place it says that the fastest is 110 m/s and other place it is 120 m/s. While slowest one varies between 7 m/s (in Rana frog) to 0.5 m/s (Nociceptors) on Wiki. The average speed would be hard to calculate.

I am looking for any references where slowest and fasted action potentials are described. They would be interesting cases to write a note for classromm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search on **[Bionumbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/)**.

Here is what I got after searching [*action potential*](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?log=y&task=searchbytrmorg&trm=action%20potential&org=):

- Speed of action potential along non-myelinated invertebrate axons of ~10μm diameter = less than 1 m/s
- Action potential speed in myelinated axon = 50 ... 100 m/s
- Velocity of action potential in pyramidal tract at 37°C (in Cat Felis) = 164 m/s

It offers you references for every number.